# Mortage gift loose repayment

Tags: mortgage

My second cousin is asking for 14k as a gift for down-payment for his mortgage loan with the idea that he will pay me back when he can, but without us setting any formal/legal obligation to do so (so that it isn't a "loan").

Do I need to worry about any personal liability by calling it a gift since we have *intent* of repayment even though there's no legal requirement of repayment?

Edit:

Thanks everyone for all the responses! I'm taking everyone's advice to offer the money as a loan and not declare it as a gift. I find it funny and suspicious that his mortgage broker said it was fine when I asked about the gift thing, but glad I got more opinions before following the broker's instructions

Comment: That’s what you’re worried about? You’ll never see the money again.

Comment: Thanks JoeTaxpayer, i mean there's always that risk but that depends from family to family, i wrote the post under the assumption that i wasn't concerned about that risk. I'm more concerned about doing something illegal/fraudulent

Comment: Please see [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/72125/is-giving-my-girlfriend-money-for-her-mortgage-closing-costs-and-down-payment-co) and other related ones, this is a reasonably common question in its general nature (if not the specifics).

Comment: Intent of repayment = not a gift.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Grade Eh. What about casual intent of repayment? Like a birthday gift, you kind of do it with some expectation that the other person will get you a gift too, but you're not going to take them to court if they don't, so it isn't really a liability, just a code of honor

Comment: "*What about casual **intent of repayment**?*" I think you answered your own question.

Comment: What defines the distinction between a gift which has a social expectation of repayment (like a birthday gift), and a loan which has a more binding, legal expectation of repayment? Like, what are the relevant laws / documents stating the distinction? I realised i used the words "intent of repayment" but i'm more interested in what the specific meaning of the words used in legal circumstances are

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Why is that so? Some families keep the promises they make. I politely disagree.

Comment: @Alexus: If this is a promise, and this is the kind of family that keeps its promises (and thus expects the promise to be kept), then we *clearly* have a loan here.

Comment: @muzzlator: You don't give gifts with the expectation of getting gifts in return. You give gifts because in the worst case, society expects you to...or in a better case, it warms your heart to see someone else happy. If you're trading gifts for gifts, spoiler alert: those aren't gifts. What you're doing is called *bartering*. :)

Comment: @cHao We do. Which is a fraud in the view of most mortgage institutions.

Comment: The key to all this is that they cannot afford the house.  If they could, they would not need 14k from a second cousin.  How much more money are they "loose borrowing"?  When the reality of home ownership hits them they are more likely to lose the home in foreclosure than pay this money back.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're loaning your cousin money.

Now, you ask about personal liability.  What sort of liability are you asking about?  Tax liability?  You can gift him the interest, no problem, without any issues; so you loan him $14k today, and then gift him 5% interest forgiven each year, and he eventually pays you back, all square.  (And if he never pays you back then some year you'll officially gift him the $14k, and write off the loan in your head.)  The interest amount is well under the annual exemption for gift tax.

As far as I know, having a gift or a loan doesn't create any additional liability on your part (like, liability to pay his mortgage if he defaults, or liability for a slip and fall).  If you're concerned though about legal (law) issues here, though, this isn't the place to ask those.

From a financial standpoint, there's nothing wrong with the arrangement you mention and it's very common.  I would just note that you should personally consider it a gift, and just be happy if you eventually are repaid.

---

As far as the mortgage goes, it's up to your cousin to declare it or not, nothing on your side. Mortgage companies are pretty smart about that sort of thing, and one thing they'll want to look at are several bank statements - so a recent gift will look like a gift. Either way will be pretty similar in how they treat it - they'll raise the interest rate some or refuse to loan, if this is most or all of the down payment in particular. They can't be sure it's not a loan, so they treat it as if it were.

When it might come into relevance is if your cousin repays you then a month or two later defaults and declares bankruptcy or similar. The bank might then try to collect from you in that case, if it discovers the payment. I'm not a lawyer and don't have any idea of how successful they might be, but it's a possibility.  Again, the fact that it's a loan doesn't matter there; it's just the evasion of his duty to pay the mortgage lender.

Comment: I was mainly worried about legal liability for misrepresenting the purpose of the payment, sorry for not stating that. I trust him enough to make the repayments, but I didn't want to be liable for mortgage fraud by stating it was a "gift" and then having the equivalent amount of money showing up in my account later when repayment is made

Comment: Oh, you mean that you're gifting your cousin $14k when he's _applying_ for a loan?

Comment: yes sorry, he's applying for a loan, i want to gift my cousin $14k for a downpayment (I'll edit the post to reflect this). We have an informal agreement of repayment but nothing that he's liable for (so from the pov of the bank, not a risk?)

Comment: Added some text there.  If you have any questions though about the legal side of things, please contact a lawyer, this isn't a legal advice site - just financial advice.

Comment: "They won't differentiate between a loan and a gift; as long as there's no recourse on the property on your part, they don't care." I disagree. A loan necessarily cuts into available income on account of the loan payments that are supposed to be made, even if the OP and his cousin swear to high heaven that it is an interest-free loan, and the lender _can_ be concerned that the borrower has insufficient income to support the mortgage payment in addition to the other obligations.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I agree with you fully; "*They won't differentiate between a loan and a gift*" is categorically untrue - the bank absolutely wants to know what is a loan and what is a gift, and lying about a loan by calling it a gift is most certainly fraud.

Comment: I think they'll treat it the same way no matter what you call it (in-family), from my experience (as a borrower, so I defer to anyone who has lender side experience of course!).  Either a gift or a "loan" would trigger similar higher interest rates or refusals, I'd think.  But I'll adjust the wording of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry too much about it; your second cousin will need to submit the last few months of bank statements to the mortgage lender and the lender will certainly ask where that $14K deposit came from, and then demand that you submit a letter (probably notarized too) in which you will swear on your mother's grave that the money is a gift with no strings attached. Failing this, the lender will treat the money as an undisclosed loan which might well disqualify your cousin from getting a mortgage, or the lender will jack up the interest rate being offered in order to compensate for the higher risk of default. Note that you are entitled to give up to $15K per person per year without incurring gift tax, and as long as you haven't given (or intend to give) your cousin very extravagant birthday or Christmas gifts, you will be under the limit and don't need to file a gift tax return (Form 709). Your cousin will have an explanation for the gift (especially if you attach a brief letter to your check saying something like "Dear Cuz, Out of the goodness of my heart, I am giving you a gift of $14K. Best regards, Muzzlator".  (Gifts are not taxable income to the recipient).

As far as "repayment" is considered, Dear Cuz can repay the amount in a lump sum (or in dribs and drabs over the years), preferably accompanied by similar letters addressed to you.

Now, with all the downvotes and declarations that this is actually a loan and that I am encouraging mortgage fraud by suggesting that the OP call it a gift when it is actually a loan, and the OP declaring that he ie going to avoid all the hassles and insist on calling that $14K a loan (or maybe even an interest-free loan) that Dear Cuz can repay whenever Dear Cuz feels like it, the OP needs to understand that even if he does not *collect* any cash interest from Dear Cuz, as far as the IRS is concerned, the OP *is* receiving *taxable* interest at *at least the minimum rate* that the IRS sets, and that this imputed interest income needs to be declared on the OP's tax return and taxes paid on it. Now, by *not collecting the interest* that the IRS imputes that the OP has received, the OP is making gifts each year to Dear Cuz in the amount of the annual interest deemed to have been earned (even though no cash is changing hands). The amount will be small enough that no gift tax return is required.  In short, the OP is going to be out the tax on the interest deemed to have been earned each year from this loan.

Comment: This answer amounts to "misrepresent the source of your funds and you'll be fine", while completely ignoring the rather thorny issue of mortgage fraud. A gift with the expectation of repayment simply isn't a gift, and providing documents that state otherwise is just lying.

Comment: @NuclearWang What is the definition of "expectation"? Are there any relevant legal documents about this?

Also, thanks Dilip for taking time to answer! Glad to know I don't need to declare tax, if this gift were to happen

Comment: @muzzlator: If it's been agreed that your cousin will pay you back -- even at a time as vague as "eventually" or "someday" -- and you believe it, then you have an expectation of repayment. (Whether you'll ever see that money again is beside the point.) And when the lender is like "oh, he just up and *gave* $14k, huh?", three options arise. 1: You decide to be honest, call it a loan, and let it have its negative effect on the mortgage application. 2: You call it a gift, *make* it a gift, and you're out $14k. Or 3: You call it a gift but it's really a loan, and are now committing mortgage fraud.

Comment: Thanks chao for the clarification here, i've decided to not give the "gift" in the end, but instead offered a loan only (which may be useless to him, not sure yet)

Answer (score 0):

This is mortgage fraud. Stay away.